Inverting $f(X)= X X^T$ for $d\times d\ X $ with unit-norm rows
Suppose all rows of $d\times d$ matrix $X$ have unit norm and $A=XX^T$. Given $A$, how do I obtain $X$, up to an orthogonal transformation?
(it's curious that inverting $XX^T$ appears much harder than inverting $XX$)
Related answer on mathematica.SE shows how to do this using generic black-box optimizer. I was hoping to utilize standard linear algebra tools instead.

What is the dimension of $X$? Is it a square matrix? What dimension do you allow for $Y$? Also square?

Interested in both, but square is an interesting special case

Doesn’t the uniqueness of Cholesky factorisation imply that  any such $Y$ is of the form $DX$ for some diagonal $D$ with $\pm1$ entries on the diagonal?

If $X$ is orthogonal, then $A=I$. So, any orthogonal matrix $Y$ is a solution.

I don't understand how the title "Balanced rank-1 decomposition" relates to your question. Which matrix has rank 1? What do you mean by balanced?

@obareey okay so perhaps it's unique up to a rotation? How do I find the solution in the general case?

The title could be "find vectors, knowing their Gram matrix" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix

@Gribouillis updated

Can't you simply take $X$ to be $L^T$, where $A = LL^T$ is a Cholesky decomposition?

@BenGrossmann I need rows with unit norm. Normalizing rows of cholesky breaks the decomposition

@YaroslavBulatov …I swear I know how to read. Thank you

@Yaroslav I suggest the following: parameterize $X$ as $X = UL^T$, where $U$ is orthogonal (and $L$ is from the Cholesky decomposition per my previous comment). Ensuring that the rows of $X$ have norm 1 amounts to the constraint that all diagonal entries of $XX^T$, which is equal to $U(L^TL)U^T$, are all equal to $1$. I seem to remember that the problem of finding an orthogonal $U$ such that $UMU^T$ has a constant diagonal has a nice answer

Please check the comment thread on lightxbulb's answer; we would like you to confirm on whether the rows or columns have unit norm.

@FedericoPoloni Based on the feedback to my initial suggestion of using Cholesky decomposition, it seems that OP really does mean that the rows have unit norm.

@BenGrossmann If you check the mathematica post he references, there he wants to reconstruct unit vectors based on their dot products. So if you put the vectors as columns in $X$, the problem becomes reconstructing $X$ from $A=X^TX$. If you put the vectors as rows in $X$ then $A=XX^T$. So my assumption was that the "rows" part is a typo  (or modelling mistake) or that the $A=X^TX$ part is a mistake. If this is indeed the case then likely the culprit for not getting the results he wants is the SVD he used there.

Sorry for confusion, it was a typo. I have $d$ unkown vectors on surface of unit sphere, and I want to reconstruct their locations (up to rotation) from their dot products. I didn't expect that "row-normalized" vs "column-normalized" to have a big difference, since matrices are $d\times d$

@OP could you please edit also the title and the cross-post on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44666/inverting-fx-xt-x-for-d-times-d-x-with-rows-of-unit-norm , so that the correct formulation appears everywhere?

@FedericoPoloni I read the answer more carefully and my original phrasing is correct, as well as lightbulb's interpretation, there are some mistakes in intermediate messages. The problem is to reconstruct a set of vectors {xi} of unit norm from the matrix of pairwise dot products <xi,xj>.

Note: My answer and code differs from yours by a transposition. That is, if we are in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and I have $n$ vectors $X_1,\ldots,X_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$, then those are arranged in the columns of my matrix $X \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$:
$$X = \begin{bmatrix} | & & | \\ X_1 & \ldots & X_n \\ | & & |  \end{bmatrix}, \quad X^T = \begin{bmatrix} - X_1^T - \\ \vdots \\ - X_n^T - \end{bmatrix}.$$
So my $X^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ (XT in my code) is your $X$.
Also, since the constraint $(Y^TY)_{ii} = 1$ is automatically satisfied I do not discuss it below. You can take non-normalized vectors if you wished, and the below method would reconstruct those.

The Gramian
You are given the matrix of dot products (the Gramian):
$$G = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
X_1 \cdot X_1 & \ldots & X_1 \cdot X_n \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\ 
X_n \cdot X_1 & \ldots & X_n \cdot X_n 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
X_1^T X_1 & \ldots & X_1^T X_n \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\ 
X_n^TX_1 & \ldots & X_n^T X_n 
\end{bmatrix} = X^TX \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}.$$
The matrix is symmetric $G^T = (X^TX)^T = X^T(X^T)^T = X^TX = G$, and positive semi-definite $u^TGu = u^TX^TXu = (Xu)^T(Xu) = \|Xu\|^2_2\geq 0$. The matrix is positive definite iff the vectors $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are linearly independent. A necessary but insufficient conditions for this is that $n\leq d$.
Since $G$ is real symmetric it admits an eigendecomposition $G=WDW^T$ where the eigenvectors are orthonormal $W\in O(n) = \{Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\,:\, W^TW=WW^T=I_n\}$, and the eigenvalues are real $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Since $G$ is positive semi-definite, the eigenvalues $D_{ii}$ are additionally non-negative.

Case 1: $n=d$
Suppose that $n= d$ then:
$$G=WDW^T \stackrel{(i)}{=} W\underbrace{\sqrt{D}}_{\sqrt{D}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}\sqrt{D}^TW^T = \underbrace{(W\sqrt{D})}_{\tilde{Y}^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}\underbrace{(W\sqrt{D})^T}_{\tilde{Y}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} =
\tilde{Y}^T\tilde{Y}.$$
$(i)$ Since $D_{ii}\geq 0$ it follows $\sqrt{D_{ii}}\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus
$\sqrt{D}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\tilde{Y}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. If that was not the case the matrix $\tilde{Y}$ could have become complex-valued. Since $\tilde{Y}$ is of the desired size, we can just use $Y=\tilde{Y}$ as the reconstructed vectors.
Note that this is not the only solution, and for any $Q\in O(d)$ we have that $Y_Q = QY$ is also a solution, since
$$Y_Q^TY_Q = (QY)^T(QY) = Y^T\underbrace{Q^TQ}_{I}Y = Y^TY = G.$$

Case 2: $n<d$
In the case $n<d$ our Gramian is only $n\times n$ and the resulting $Y$ is also $n\times n$, but we need $d$-dimensional vectors. We could arbitrarily choose an $n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and situate the solution there. A simple subspace is the one where the last coordinates are zero: $x_i=0$ for $n+1\leq i \leq d$. Then we just need to extend the matrix with $(d-n)$ additional rows of zeros:
$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} \tilde{Y} \\ 0_{(n-d)\times n}\end{bmatrix} \in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}.$$
In my code down below the adjust_matrix function performs this padding if $n<d$ (but it performs it on $\tilde{Y}^T$).
As before, the solution is not unique and any $Y_Q = QY$ is also a solution.

Case 3: $d<n$
The case $d<n$ is arguably the most interesting one in practice. The rank of the matrix can be at most $d<n$, which automatically means that it is singular. It also means that there are at most $d$ non-zero eigenvalues. Let the eigenvalues in the eigendecomposition be ordered from largest to smallest, then the non-zero eigenvalues are in the upper left block of $D$:
\begin{align*}
G&=WDW^T \\
&= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
|   &        & |   &  |      &        &  |  \\
W_1 & \ldots & W_d & W_{d+1} & \ldots & W_n \\
|   &        & |   &  |      &        &  |  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{D_{11}}^2 &        &                 &   &        & \\
                & \ddots &                 &   &        & \\
                &        & \sqrt{D_{dd}}^2 &   &        & \\
                &        &                 & 0 &        & \\
                &        &                 &   & \ddots & \\
                &        &                 &   &        & 0
\end{bmatrix}W^T \\
&= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 
|                &        & |                &  | &        &  |  \\
W_1\sqrt{D_{11}} & \ldots & W_d\sqrt{D_{dd}} &  0 & \ldots & 0 \\
|                &        & |                &  | &        &  |  
\end{bmatrix}}_{\tilde{Y}^T=W\sqrt{D}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
- \sqrt{D_{11}}W_1^T - \\
\vdots \\
-\sqrt{D_{dd}}W_d^T - \\
- 0^T - \\
\vdots \\
- 0^T - 
\end{bmatrix}}_{\tilde{Y}=(W\sqrt{D})^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}}
\\
&= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 
|                &        & |                \\
W_1\sqrt{D_{11}} & \ldots & W_d\sqrt{D_{dd}} \\
|                &        & |                  
\end{bmatrix}}_{Y^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
- \sqrt{D_{11}}W_1^T - \\
\vdots \\
-\sqrt{D_{dd}}W_d^T -
\end{bmatrix}}_{Y\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}}.
\end{align*}
Note that $D_{dd}$ and lower terms can also be zero, but that is not relevant for this, the point was to reduce $\tilde{Y}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$. This truncation of the matrix for $d<n$ happens in my code below through adjust_matrix. Note that knowing the number of non-zero eigenvalues $r$ may be relevant for computational efficiency though, since if you set $k=r$ instead of $k=d$ in eigsh, you only need to compute the $r$ eigenvectors and eigenvalues in that case and get a matrix of size $r\times n$. Then you can pad the matrix with zeroes to reach a dimension of $d\times n$.
As before, the solution is defined only up to an orthogonal transformation $Q\in O(d)$. This held in all cases and the extra degrees of freedom are then $\dim O(d) = d(d-1)/2$.

Number of Coefficients in $G,Q$ vs $X$
Note that the space of symmetric matrices $\operatorname{Sym}(n)$ has dimension $n(n+1)/2$ (this is referring to the data in $G$). As a sanity check, for $n=d$ we have:
$$\dim O(d) + \dim \operatorname{Sym}(n) = d(d-1)/2 + n(n+1)/2 = n^2 = nd.$$
So the amount of data in $X\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ is equivalent to the amount of data in $G$ and $Q$ for $n=d$. We can show that the same is true if $d=n+1$. If $d\not\in\{n,n+1\}$ we can show that $\dim O(d) + \dim \operatorname{Sym}(n)>nd$, i.e., if we store $Q$ and $G$ instead of $X$, that is actually more wasteful:
\begin{align*}
 f(d) &= \dim O(d) + \dim \operatorname{Sym}(n) -nd = \frac{d^2}{2} - \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)d + \frac{n^2+n}{2}, \\
D&= \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - n^2-n = \frac{1}{4} \\
d_{1,2} &= n+\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2} \in \{n, n+1\} \implies 
f(d)>0 \text{ for } d\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{n, n+1\}.
\end{align*}
Consider storing a single vector then you need to store $d$ components. On the other hand $\dim O(d)$ grows quadratically with the dimension. Vice versa, consider $d$ fixed, and grow $n$. $X$ grows linearly in $n$ while $G$ grows quadratically. So in either case you can't really use this as a compression technique, unless $d\gg n$ and you just store $G$. Although I suppose that is not what you're using this for.

How to find $Q \,:\, X = QY$
Provided you have computed $Y$ and you have $X$ you can find the $Q$ such that $X=QY$ by solving the orthogonal Procrustes problem:
$$\min_{Q\in O(d)}\|QY-X\|^2_2 \implies Q=UV^T \,:\, XY^T = USV^T.$$
That is, you can compute the SVD of $XY^T$ and drop the singular values matrix. I use this as a sanity check in my code below in order to verify that $Y$ can indeed be brought to $X$ with an orthogonal transformation of the vectors.

Computational Aspects
As you saw from the above, in all cases (regardless whether $G$ is singular) you can use the eigendecomposition in order to compute $Y$ from $G$. When $d\ll n$ this is especially efficient if you compute just the $d$ eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues (or if you know the rank $r$ and $r<d$, you could just compute the $r$ eigenvectors), e.g. by using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh which calls ARPACK under the hood, and thus uses Lanczos. When $d>=n$ you can do a full eigendecomposition on the matrix $G\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ by using np.linalg.eigh. Or again, if you know that its rank is lower, you can stop at that.
When $n\leq d$ another option is to compute the square root of $G$, i.e., $Y=\sqrt{G}$ (you can use scipy.linalg.sparse.sqrtm). Note that this does not work when $n>d$ since then you cannot just drop the last $(n-d)$ columns of $\tilde{Y}$ in order to get $Y$. Also it may happen that $\sqrt{G}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ due to numerical error. In my code I just drop the imaginary part in that scenario, but I doubt that's the most robust thing.
When $G$ is non-singular (a necessary but insufficient condition is $n=d$), you can also use the Cholesky decomposition: $G=LL^T$. Then $Y=L^T$. If $G$ is singular, you could use the $LDL^T$ decomposition. Then you could drop the rows of $L$ corresponding to zeroes in $D$ in order to get $Y$. This works also when $n>d$.
From the above methods I would expect the eigendecomposition with eigsh to be the fastest, especially for $d\ll n$. I don't know how efficient the square root and Cholesky are comparatively in python. So they may make sense for when $n$ is large and $n\approx d$, but you should profile that yourself.

Code
I wrote some code to demonstrate that this works (with Cholesky, the square root, LDL^T, and eigendecomposition with only $\min(n,d)$ vectors). This should work for any number of vectors $n>0$ and in whatever dimension (for the visualisation the dimension must be $2$ or $3$). You can see the result here:

The code also works when you have linearly dependent vectors: you can test the commented line XT=np.array([[1.0,0,0],[1.0,0.0,0]]).
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.sparse.linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# generates uniformly distributed points on the unit sphere
def generate_normalized_vectors(n,d):
    # Generate n normally distributed vectors in d-D
    random_vectors = np.random.normal(size=(n, d))
    
    # Normalize the vectors
    norms = np.linalg.norm(random_vectors, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    normalized_vectors = random_vectors / norms
    
    return normalized_vectors

# truncates the last (n-d) columns of Y^T if d<n
# adds (d-n) extra zero columns to Y^T if n>d
def adjust_matrix(A, d):
    n = A.shape[1]  # Assuming A is a square matrix (n x n)
    
    if d < n:
        # Drop the last (n - d) columns
        adjusted_A = A[:, :d]
    elif d > n:
        # Add (d - n) zero columns
        zero_columns = np.zeros((n, d - n))
        adjusted_A = np.hstack((A, zero_columns))
    else:
        # d == n, do nothing
        adjusted_A = A
    
    return adjusted_A

# solves min_{Q^TQ = I} ||QA-B||^2_2
# If BA^T = USV^T, then Q = UV^T
def procrustes(A,B):
    U,S,VT = np.linalg.svd(np.matmul(B,A.T));
    return np.matmul(U,VT);

def draw_vectors(XT, XT_rec):
    d = XT.shape[1];

    # Visualization
    fig = plt.figure()
    if d==2:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    else:
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    # Plot the vectors
    origin = np.zeros((d, 1))  # Origin point

    for vector in XT: 
        if d==2:
            ax.quiver(*origin, *vector, 
                    ls='-', linewidth=1, 
                    angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, facecolor='none', edgecolor = 'k')
        else:
            ax.quiver(*origin, *vector, linestyle='dashed', normalize=False)

    for vector in XT_rec: 
        if d==2:
            ax.quiver(*origin, *vector, 
                    ls='-.', linewidth=1, 
                    angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, facecolor='none', edgecolor='r')
        else:
            ax.quiver(*origin, *vector, color = 'red', linestyle='dashdot', normalize=False)


    # Set limits and labels
    ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
    ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
    if d==3:
        ax.set_zlim([-1, 1])
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
    if d==3:
        ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
    if d==2:
        ax.set_title('Reconstruction of Random Vectors in 2D')
    else:
        ax.set_title('Reconstruction of Random Vectors in 3D')

    plt.show()

# number of vectors
n = 8
# dimension
d = 3

# 0: Use Cholesky: G=LL^T -> Y^T = L (works only for n<=d and non-singular matrices)
# 1: Use matrix square root: Y^T = sqrt(G)=Vsqrt(D)V^T (works only for n<=d)
# 2: Use Bunch-Kaufman: G=LDL^T, Y^T= [L sqrt(D)]|_{nxd}
# 3: Use eigendecomposition: G=VDV^T -> Y^T = [V sqrt(D)]|_{nxd}
mode = 3

# switch to eigendecomposition if Cholesky or sqrt were chosen but d<n
if d<n and mode<2:
    if mode==0:
        print("Cholesky was specified but d<n. Switching to eigendecomposition.")
    else:
        print("Matrix square root was specified but d<n. Switching to eigendecomposition.")
    mode = 3

# generate random vectors in the rows of X^T in R^{nxd}
XT = generate_normalized_vectors(n,d)

# to test degernate case for n<d
#XT=np.array([[1.0,0,0],[1.0,0.0,0]])

# Gram matrix G = X^TX, a R^{nxn} positive semi-definite matrix
G = np.matmul(XT,XT.T)

# G=LL^T -> Y^T = [L]|_{n x d}
if mode==0:
    # Use Cholesky if the matrix is non-singular (can happen only for d==n)
    if n<=d and np.linalg.cond(G) < 1.0/np.finfo(G.dtype).eps:
        print("Using Cholesky.")
        YTnD = np.linalg.cholesky(G)
    else:
        print("Matrix is singular. Cannot use Choleksy. Switching to LDL^T decomposition.")
        mode = 2

# sqrt(G) = V sqrt(D) V^T -> Y^T = [V sqrt(D) V^T]|_{n x d}
if mode==1:
    print("Using matrix square root.")
    YTnD = np.real(scipy.linalg.sqrtm(G))

# G=LDL^T -> Y^T = [L sqrt(D)]|_{n x d} decomposition
if mode==2:
    print("Using LDL^T.")
    L, D, perm = scipy.linalg.ldl(G)
    # take the square root of D and drop the terms 
    # that are supposed to be zero
    for i in range (0,min(d,n)):
        D[i,i] = np.sqrt(D[i,i])
    for i in range(min(d,n),n):
        D[i,i] = 0
    # Once we truncate L sqrt(D) we will get Y^T
    YTnD = np.matmul(L, D)

# G = VDV^T -> Y^T = V sqrt(D)
if mode==3:
    if n<=d:
        print("Using full eigendecomposition.")
        D, W = np.linalg.eigh(G)
    else: # d<n
        print("Using partial eigendecomposition.")
        D, W = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(G, k=d, which='LM')
    YTnD = np.matmul(W,np.diag(np.sqrt(D)));

# truncate or extend as necessary the matrix from R^{nxn} to R^{nxd}
YT = adjust_matrix(YTnD, d)

# reconstruct XT from YT exactly
Q = procrustes(XT.T,YT.T);
XT_rec = np.matmul(YT, Q);

draw_vectors(XT,XT_rec)


The $(i,i)$ element of $A$ is 1 if the columns of $X$ have unit norm, not its rows. So that constraint does not look trivial to satisfy.

@FedericoPoloni In his mathematica post he mentions that $X$ are vectors on a sphere and he takes their dot products, i.e. $A=X^TX$ is the Gramian. So I am not sure whether the above isn't just a typo, and it's really the columns that are supposed to be unit length. Or maybe I misunderstood the problem.

I see, let's wait for a clarification from OP then.

For case 1, the resulting vectors only have unit norm when eigenvalues are all equal to 1. In general case this is not true, so reconstructed vectors won't lie on the sphere anymore

@YaroslavBulatov Consider $1=|X_i|^2 = X_i^TX_i = G_{ii}$. Since $Y^TY=G$ by construction, you have $|Y_i|^2_2 = G_{ii} = 1$. This is unrelated to the eigenvalues. Your constraint is automatically satisfied provided the $X_i$ were normalized. Given the Gramian $G$ the method reconstructs the vectors in $X$ up to orthogonal transformation. This means that the angles between the vectors in $Y$ are the same as between the vectors in $X$, and that the lengths of the vectors in $Y$ are the same as the lengths of the vectors in $X$. Run the code and verify it experimentally if you wish.

@YaroslavBulatov It holds in all 3 cases too. Even something stronger holds. If your vectors had sizes $|X_1|, \ldots, |X_n|$ then the vectors $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ would have precisely these sizes and in that order, i.e. $|Y_i|=|X_i|$. The unit length setting is just a special case. If you know your vectors are unit length then the Gramian has ones on the diagonal. The diagonal elements of the Gramian are not its eigenvalues. You can check from my code that the eigenvalues are not $1$ despite the vectors being unit length.

@YaroslavBulatov When I compute $Y^T=W\sqrt{D}$ note that it is the rows of $W\sqrt{D}$ that are the vectors. This is even more apparent in case 3: $d<n$. Say you have $d = 3$ and $n=8$. Then it is sufficient to compute only the $3$ eigenvectors $W_1, W_2, W_3$ corresponding to the $3$ largest eigenvalues $D_{11}, D_{22}, D_{33}$. Your vectors are NOT the $3$ eigenvectors. Your vectors are 3D, while the eigenvectors are 8D. The $i$-th vector is $Y_i^T = (W^i_1\sqrt{D_{11}}, W^i_2\sqrt{D_{22}}, W^i_3\sqrt{D_{33}})$, where $W^i_j$ is the $i$-th coordinate of the $j$-th eigenvector.

@lightxbulb thanks for in-depth response! I've ran your code and confirmed that it works

Note that matrices $P,Q$ of the same shape satisfy $P^TP = Q^TQ$ if and only if $Q = UP$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$. As such, we may begin by find a Cholesky decomposition $A = LL^T$, and note that because $X^TX = LL^T$, there must exist an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that
$$
X = UL^T.
$$
In other words, we may parameterize $X$ as above.
From there, we note that the rows of $X$ having unit length is equivalent to the condition that $XX^T$ has $1$ as its constant diagonal. Noting that $XX^T = [UL^T][UL^T]^T = U[L^TL]U^T$, we see it suffices to find an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that
$$
U(L^TL)U^T
$$
has diagonal entries all equal to $1$. This is equivalent to $U(L^TL - I)U^T$ having diagonal entries equal to zero (where $I$ denotes an identity matrix).
In order to find such a $U$, it suffices to apply the recursive approach suggested in this proof.
Alternatively, confer Example 2.2.3 of Horn and Johnson's Matrix Analysis (2nd edition) for a similar exposition.

Note: The cholesky decomposition is problematic for the case where $A$ is non-invertible (i.e. positive semi-definite but not definite). In this case, a common approach is to use the positive semidefinite square root of $A$ (which can be attained via diagonalization) instead of $L$.

Thanks for the tips, lightbulb has similar approach but he goes in more depth showing how to find U by using SVD

You problem is basically the reconstruction of the data given the PCA of the data (More accurately, the Multi Dimensional Scaling (MDS)).
I will add assumption which your data is centered, Namely ${\left\{ \boldsymbol{x}_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{D} \right\}}_{i = 1}^{d}$ where $\sum {x}_{i} = 0$.
The MDS problem tries to solve:
$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{Z} \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times d}} {\left\| \boldsymbol{K}_{x} - \boldsymbol{Z}^{T} \boldsymbol{Z} \right\|}_{F}^{2} $$
Where $D \leq d$ and $\boldsymbol{K}_{x} = - \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{J} \boldsymbol{D}_{x} \boldsymbol{J}$ with ${D}_{i, j} = {\left\| \boldsymbol{x}_{i} - \boldsymbol{x}_{j} \right\|}_{2}^{2}$ (The Distance Matrix).
The matrix ${J} = \boldsymbol{I} - \frac{1}{D} \boldsymbol{1} \boldsymbol{1}^{T}$ is the Centering Matrix.
It turns out that $\boldsymbol{K}_{x} = \tilde{\boldsymbol{X}}^{T} \tilde{\boldsymbol{X}}$ where $\tilde{\boldsymbol{X}} = \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{J}$, namely where each column is centered.
So in case your matrix is indeed composed of centered vectors, all you need is to apply MDS with the input being your matrix $\boldsymbol{A}^{T}$ and the output dimension to be $d$.
Remark: The MDS for this Kernel Matrix matches the PCA as I wrote above. It is solved with EVD (Eigen Value Decomposition) or SVD (Singular Value Decomposition).
Motivation: The answer motivation is connecting the problem to a well known solution framework.
